# How to apply margin to bootstrap v5 COL content which is full height and full width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Here I have 2 rows and 2 columns in each row. I want the yellow blocks to have a margin and take all the available space in the column besides the margin. But as you can see, the margin completely misaligns the yellow content.

[image]

```css
.row {
  background: green;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
}

.content-margin {
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result I want is similar to this:
[image]

**THE QUESTION:** Is there any way to achieve that by adding **margin** to the yellow block?

**NOTE: I know I can achieve that by adding padding to the COL itself, but that's no good for my real world use case.**

https://jsfiddle.net/39zp4tc0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way to effectively apply **MARGIN** to the yellow div elements.

I'm using d-flex and align-items-stretch classes on the COL elements and using flex-grow-1 class on the yellow div elements. If we stretch the yellow elements this way, the **MARGIN** is respected and does not ruin the layout.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row g-0 justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="content-margin  flex-grow-1  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="content-margin flex-grow-1 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row g-0 justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="content-margin flex-grow-1 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="content-margin flex-grow-1 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwjk5upn/1/

NOTE: I'm using the g-0 class on the COL elements as well to get rid of the default COL paddings.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a padding on the parent (col) instead of a margin on the child:

```css
.row {
  background: green;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px
}

.content-margin {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-100 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do recommend using margin to positioning and padding for that spaces between components. You can use margin: auto in combination with display flex to make a div in a specific position. You can view more information on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Notice the ending of my question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the yellow column to 60% with margin: 12px 0;
Try this:

```css
.row {
  background: green;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
}

.content-margin {
  margin: 12px 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.h-60 {
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-60  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin w-100 h-60  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-60  d-flex"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="content-margin  w-100 h-60 d-flex"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd still use padding, but if you can't put it on the columns put it on an inner element acting as a wrapper for your yellow boxes.

```css
.row {
  background: green;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 60px;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row gx-0 justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-2 py-2">
        <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-2 py-2">
        <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row gx-0 justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-2 py-2">
        <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <div class="w-100 h-100 px-2 py-2">
        <div class="w-100 h-100 bg-yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```